# restrict space key value to transfer when no other character value is entered

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

In my Chat application project, I am trying to restrict spaces when the user has just pressed <kbd>Space</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>. pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> will show entered Text into a `div`. Please see the comments in the code to understand clearly.

```
#txtmsg --> ID of TextBox field
```

---

```
$('#txtmsg').keypress(function (e)
{
    if (e.which == 13) 
    {
        //Disable default function of Enter key
        e.preventDefault(); 
        //Checks whether the user has entered any value or not
        if ($('#txtmsg').val().length > 0)  
        {
          //if(user has not entered only spaces....)?

           //transfers the entered value in the text field to div
            chat.server.send($('#txtmsg').val());
            $('#txtmsg').val('');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "restrict spaces"?

Comment: I mean not to allow it to transfer to the div. because it is worthless. "just transferring a space with no other characters"

Comment: have you tried using `jQuery.trim()`?

Comment: @MilindAnantwar no..I am new to jquery. same function is in c# too.

Comment: `$.trim("    hello, how are you?    ");` will make
`"hello, how are you?"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/ :

```
if($.trim($('#txtmsg').val()) !== "") { ... }
```

Comment: Well, I usually prefer to not rely on jQuery methods when possible. It just adds extra overhead, IMHO.

Comment: @Abody97 but your code will only remove the first white space, not all of them

Comment: @Abody97: you are right, but using a framework ensures that we use robust function (in general) and for this case, as it is a single isolated test, it will not affect the whole performance of the application!

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie My project is small. so, I will go with this answer.  edit: `!==` to `!=` :)

Comment: Why do you need this replacement? The `!==` operator is there in order to have a strict comparison (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)...

Answer (score 2):

The check would be:

```
var message = $('#txtmsg').val(); //cache the message
if(message.replace(/\s/g, "").length !== 0) { //if the message has something other than spaces
    //send the message
}
```

Note that `/\s/` matches all kinds of white-space characters; <kbd>tabs</kbd>, <kbd>spaces</kbd>, new lines, (other weird space characters).

Comment: I think this will make " hello how are you " to "hellohowareyou".

Comment: @Mr_Green You just use it for checking, `.replace()` doesn't actually edit the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if ($('#txtmsg').val().length > 0 && /^\s+$/.test($('#txtmsg').val()) === false) {
...
}
```